Can't get the right output for perfect number algo
trying to write a perfect number algorithm but can't get right output even thought 28 is a perfect number.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    int sum;
    printf("enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    for(int i = 1;i < x;i++) {
        if(x % i==0) {
            printf("%d ", i);
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    if(sum == x) {
        printf("it's a perfect number");
    }else {
        printf("it's not a perfect number");
    }
}


Hi, can you please provide more information about the output you get with 28 and the logs of all your print

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings .

Hint: print the value of sum at the start before the loop

You forgot to initialize sum to zero, so upon entering the loop, its value could be anything.  So upon exit from the loop, sum could again be anything.

The issue might be coming from the way you declare the sum.
int sum;
When declaring it like this you only allocate space for an int in your memory but never set the value in the memory.
Wo when you do a sum = sum + 1, the sum is not defined and you try to add something to it. It will read in the memory a random value that is remaining here.
To prevent that, when you create an integer set it's default value
ex : int sum = 0;

This worked, thanks
